# Помогите найти ошибку в программе. (python)

Tags: python, массивы, функции

[image: вот задание]

Помогите понять, где тут ошибка:

```
a = []
N = 2015
for i in range(0, N):
    a.append(int(input()))
    b = -1
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        if (b == -1 or a[i] < b) and (a[i] < a[i - 1]) and (a[i] < a[i + 1]):
            b = a[i]
            if b == -1:
                print('0')
            else: 
                print(b)
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Строка 4:**

```
a.append( int( input() ) ) 
# Здесь вы заполняете значение массива с ключём [0]. То есть a[0].
```

**Строка 6:**

```
for i in range(1, N-1):
# Здесь вы запускаете цикл, в котором при первой итерации i будет равно 1.
```

**Строка 7:**

```
if (b == -1 or a[i] < b) and (a[i] < a[i - 1]) and (a[i] < a[i + 1]):
# Здесь вы используете массив `a`. Конкретно: его значение под ключём i. i = 1,
# но у вас заполнен только нулевой ключ массива. (Строка 4)
```

Это и вызывает у вас ошибку:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: есть вопросик, почему тогда в программе комментатора ниже все работает?

Comment: @Иван В прошлой теме я Вам совет дал про то, что сначала надо ввести массив, а потом обрабатывать. Он по-прежнему актуален.

Comment: @Иван, Вопросик, чем отличается `range (0, N-1)` от `range (1, N-1)` ?))

Comment: нет, по видимому, вы не поняли моего вопроса. Я ввожу программу комментатора ниже, а у него в строке с массивом а написано тоже самое , что и у меня, но его программа работает, хотя массив весь не введен

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev, если поменять ange (0, N-1) в его программе на range (1, N-1), то ничего не меняется

Comment: @Иван ничего подобного, у него совершенно другой код. Начиная с того, что у вас цикл в цикле, а у него 2 разных цикла.

Comment: ой , а этого я не заметил, простите) тогда , наверное, проблема в этом

Comment: `Здесь вы заполняете значение массива с ключём [0]. То есть a[0].` - ничего, что метод `.append()` добавляет объект в конец списка?

Comment: @floydya, ничего, что изначально массив `a` - пустой? `append()` "Конец" в данном случае для массива 'a' - это его значение `a[0]`. `a = []`, `a.append(2)`, `print(a[0])` - Проверяй.

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev он это выполняет в цикле, следовательно все последующие итерации записывают в конец. "В данном случае" для цикла не уместно, он каждый раз изменяется.

Comment: @floydya, Сам то понял, что сказал?

Comment: @MBo, возвращаясь к прошлой моей теме, как можно ту программу переделать под a[i + 1]?
a = []
b = 0
c = 0
d = 30
for i in range(0, d):
    a.append(int(input()))
    if a[i] < 0:
        b = b + 1
    if a[i + 1] >= 0:
        if b > c:
            c = b
            b = 0
print(c)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
minimum = -1
N = 2015

for i in range(0, N):
    a.append(int(input()))

for i in range(0, N-1):
    if a[i] < a[i-1] and a[i] < a[i + 1] and (a[i] < minimum or minimum == -1):
        minimum = a[i]

print(minimum if minimum != -1 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что вы начинаете обход массива для вычисления ямы, после каждого ввода нового элемента. В том числе после ввода первого, когда a[i - 1]) или a[i + 1] просто не могут существовать. Если уберете внешний цикл ввода данных и подставите в код тестовый массив a = [4, 9, 2, 17, 3, 8] и N = 6, ваш код отработает верно.

А вообще, это не питоник-стиль. Если например так:

`min([mid for left, mid, right in zip(a, a[1:], a[2:]) if left > mid < right])`

Comment: если честно, я почти ничего не понял)

Comment: Вы пишите фактически на Си, с индексной арифметикой, только в синтаксисе Питона. Чтобы понять эту строчку, почитайте про основные концепции Питона --  обход списоков for..in, list comprehension, распаковку списков. А еще у Питона в одном выражении, вместо AND, можно ставить несколько условий. Что будет лучше выглядеть даже с индексным доступом. Только вместо именованых left, mid, rigth будет написано a[i - 1] > a[i] < a[i + 1]